# UnsatisfiedLinkError in OpenCV example for Android

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I've read a lot of very similar posts concerning this problem, but I can't find the issue.

I'm trying to get `tutorial-2-mixedprocessing` from `OpenCV-android-sdk/samples` running (version `3.2.0`). Following [the official tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html) as good as possible, I imported it into Android Studio (`2.3`) and adjusted the path to Tegra in the Makefile to fit my system (Ubuntu `16.04`). The target platform is the project tango tablet (Android `4.4.2`).

When I check the APK in the build folder, the library `libmixed_sample.so` doesn't show up. Naturally, loading the library fails with a `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

The simpler examples without native code work fine.

Any ideas why it doesn't copy the library?

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.opencv.samples.tutorial2"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 9

        ndk {
            moduleName "mixed_sample"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = ["libs"]
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'armeabi-v7a'
            universalApk false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':openCVLibrary2482')
}
```

**Android.mk**:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCVROOT:=/home/fs/NVPACK/OpenCV-2.4.8.2-Tegra-sdk
include ${OPENCVROOT}/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV-tegra3.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := mixed_sample
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := jni_part.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**Error:**

```
06-06 10:30:41.077 24476-24476/org.opencv.samples.tutorial2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                              Process: org.opencv.samples.tutorial2, PID: 24476
  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load mixed_sample from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[
        DexPathList[
            [zip file "/data/app/org.opencv.samples.tutorial2-2.apk"],
            nativeLibraryDirectories=[
                /data/app-lib/org.opencv.samples.tutorial2-2, 
                /system/lib, 
                /vendor/lib, 
                /system/lib
                ]
            ]]: findLibrary returned null
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
    at org.opencv.samples.tutorial2.Tutorial2Activity$1.onManagerConnected(Tutorial2Activity.java:49)
    at org.opencv.android.AsyncServiceHelper$3.onServiceConnected(AsyncServiceHelper.java:318)
    at [...]
```

You can find the modified example on [github](https://github.com/Fluci/opencv-tutorial-2-mixedprocessing).